# Why's my Evolution setup screen blank?

Tags: opensuse, evolution

Trying to run Evolution on openSuSE 12.1 without success.  It starts up (eventually, super slow even on this pretty beefy box) and gives me a window with "Evolution Setup Assistant" on the title bar and 2 buttons at the bottom right (one has a stop sign and the other a couple dots and an arrow).  No text anywhere else on the window.  Clicking the forward button just gives me another broken window with 3 buttons a check box and no text describing anything.

Is there some component I'm missing that enable Evolution to display text so I can set it up?

Comment: Maybe it's trying to use a font that you don't have installed. Try running it from a terminal and see if it prints any messages; there might be something enlightening.

Comment: New info: This problem occurs when remoting in via NoMachine protocol.  It's Evolution specific, have not found any other app that has any problems.  If I use Cygwin/X and tunnel Evolution through SSH back to my Windows box it works fine that way...  Very curious.

Comment: Found another app with the same issue...  The current version of Firefox and also YaST have the exact same problem!  Yet, the other apps I use do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem occurs with NoMachine remote access for numerous applications in the newer versions of Linux.  We've discontinued use of NoMachine and have migrated to a different remote access technology.